# Distinction between different points at Big Bang Singularity

Tags: cosmology, spacetime, universe, big-bang, singularities

As per the Big Bang model of Cosmology roughly 13.8 billion years ago a singularity exploded exponentially to eventually become the present universe.

At the present time (basically current time-slice) we have all the space which according to the said model was crunched into a singularity. My question is whether two distinct space points in the current time-slice correspond to two distinct points inside the singularity (at big bang or as soon as the notion of space-time could be considered) or could they have been a single point as well?

I haven't studied cosmology (as evidenced by this rather immature question) so it would be really helpful to put things in a simple manner.

Comment: *My question is whether two distinct space points in current time-slice correspond to two distinct point before big bang.* There is no “before” the Big Bang, so the question doesn’t make sense.

Comment: @G.Smith So, let me modify to consider the time-slice when something like space-time came into existence.

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/136860/2451 and links therein.

Comment: The question [Did the Big Bang happen at a point?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/136860/did-the-big-bang-happen-at-a-point) ie closely related to this.

Comment: @G.Smith Got it. What about those two points when they were part of singularity?

Comment: See second sentence of answer.

Comment: @asymptoticallyboundedgluon the geometry is undefined at the singularity, which is of course what makes it singular, so the question you ask has no answer.

Comment: I realise it now. Thanks guys. I will also read the answers in the provided links to understand things better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two points that are different now correspond to two points that were different at any time after the Big Bang. Asking what happened *at* the Big Bang is not meaningful.